# Google GeoChart missing regions

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I'm trying to create statistics of players connected to my server. Therefore I save their Country and their Region. Now I want to create charts per country.

A working example of America would be:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Region', 'Players'],
        ['US-NY', 2],
        ['US-FL', 3]
      ]),
      {
        region: 'US',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        resolution: 'provinces'
      }
    )
  }, packages:['geochart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

But some countries just seem not to work like Taiwan (TW) or Hong Kong (HK) as you can see here at an example of Taiwan:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(
      google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Region', 'Players'],
        ['TW-TPE', 3]
      ]),
      {
        region: 'TW',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        resolution: 'provinces'
      }
    )
  }, packages:['geochart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

The following error is printed instead of the map:

> Requested map does not exist.

Is the country code of all these countrys wrong or do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: Might be because those are disputed regions.

Comment: the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#configuration-options) state under the `resolution` config option for `'provinces'` -- _Not supported for all countries; please test a country to see whether this option is supported._

Comment: @WhiteHat this has to be it... It's a shame that it isn't working for these countrys but it seems like I have to accept it.

Comment: yes, I tried several things, just doesn't work...